# Identify combobox that is selected

Tags: combobox, tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to change the foreground colour of the selected item from a combobox. The combobox itself  is created from a for loop. a

Here is an example of what im trying out:

```
package require Tk
toplevel .win2
set Default zero
for {set i 0} {$i <=10} {incr i} {
    ttk::combobox .win2.c_Numbers\_$i -textvariable Default -style TCombobox -values \
    [list {one} {two} {threre} {four} {five} {six} ]
    grid config .win2.c_Numbers\_$i  -column 0 -row $i  -sticky "w"
    bind .win2.c_Numbers\_$i  <<ComboboxSelected>> {change [%W get]}
}
proc change {var1} { 
    puts "Selected Number: $var1"
    ttk::style configure TCombobox -foreground red
    }
```

All entries are coloured red upon selection of a single entry. 
I understand that `<<ComboboxSelected>>` generates an internal 'call' for that particular combobox therby returning the selected entry while asking for it in `puts "Selected Number: $var1"` . 
Is there a way for `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to output the identifier/name of the combobox being selected. Then I would be able to colour the entries of only that particular combobox....or is there a work around that I am not seeing?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%W` is the particular combobox that is being selected. `%W get` gets the selected item from that combobox. So if you do something like this:

```
package require Tk
toplevel .win2
set Default zero
for {set i 0} {$i <=10} {incr i} {
    ttk::combobox .win2.c_Numbers_$i -textvariable Default -style TCombobox -values \
    [list {one} {two} {three} {four} {five} {six} ]
    grid config .win2.c_Numbers_$i  -column 0 -row $i  -sticky "w"
    bind .win2.c_Numbers_$i <<ComboboxSelected>> {change %W [%W get]}
}
proc change {w var1} { 
    puts "Selected combobox: $w"
    puts "Selected Number: $var1"
    ttk::style configure TCombobox -foreground red
}
```

You can add the other functionalities from there using `$w`.

Comment: That helps. Thanks for the reply. :)